# Start several SSH on a terminal on start up

Tags: command-line, automation

Due to work reason, I need to SSH to several servers every morning. Instead of open terminal and key-in several "ssh user@host", any easier method I can make it automatic such that

1. start-up pc
2. auto open terminal
3. auto open few tabs on terminal
4. each tab keeps opening and executing command, e.g. tab1, tab2, tab3  execute command "ssh user@host1", "ssh user@host2", "ssh user@host3" respectively

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of Python or Java, use the SSH commands that you already use.